# Is there a drag and drop component in android UI

Tags: android, user-interface, drag-and-drop

Is there a drag and drop component in android UI ?

Comment: what exactly you want or what you want to do

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have to take a look to the official android developer site at:

[Drag and Drop](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the API level, an official Drag and Drop framework was introduced in API level 3.0, so if you want to support Android API levels below 3.0 you are largely on your own.

But nevertheless there are many tutorials which help you in achieving what you want.

Here are a few links that I found helpful..

1. [Vogella](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html) (It is for API level 3.0 and above)
2. [Bahti](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/drag-drop-for-android-gridview/) (This is a three part tutorial and explains the mechanism of drag and drop very well, it also works on API levels less than 3.0)

Answer (score -4):

If you use eclipse to develop it has a graphical xml builder that allows you to drag and drop components. [Example](http://www.techotopia.com/images/4/4d/Eclipse_interface_builder.jpg) [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) [Android Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)