# Android How to move View with finger

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to smoothly move a view around inside its parent based on touch.  I have the OnTouchListener working and tracking movements.  How do I actually move the view?  I've tried using RelativeLayout.LayoutParameters and setting the margins, but the margins only accept int values, which makes the view jittery.  I've tried using a TranslateAnimation which will let me use a float, but that only moves the canvas, so my touch events are left behind.  Has anybody figured out a way to smoothly do this?

Comment: [Please give a look at this post, first answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964010/is-there-a-drag-and-drop-compnent-in-android-ui/9964134#9964134

Comment: I hope this link helps you: [Basic drag and drop](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=11603)

Comment: Animation is a TRAP ^^. Don't use it, unless it is not a transition between views :P

Comment: check [Drag and Drop Example](http://codingjunkie.net/android-drag-and-drop-part-2/)

Comment: I have to support back to API level 8.  Which rules out drag and drop.  Wish the client would budge on that but probably not going to happen.

Comment: Found this drag and drop link that works in back in 2.2.  http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution is rewriting a custom ViewGroup subclass, which will torture your soul. If succeeded, be sure that you have superhumanly nerves :).

Second solution is easier one but works if and only if your view consist of a image. Thus you can write a custom View subclass and refine image on onDraw() method's Canvas.

My last solution would be OpenGL.

Also, i am not sure but maybe on relative layout kinda layout updating margin and then invalidate() view might work.

Good Luck!

Comment: I tried the canvas route, but the canvas took over my whole screen.  So the web view that these images are on top of was no longer accessible.